# how can send image to php server from android application

Tags: android

i want to send only not upload image to php server

Comment: What do you think the difference between "sending" and "uploading" is?

Comment: i want to just send image on php server folder than php server takes that image from own folder. i dnt want direclty upload image

Comment: sending and uploading are same na?,,,,

Comment: no yar....i specifly wat i want exactly..